# Why do I have to create a Service Reference to the WCF within my WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, wcf

I've browsed around for an answer, but I haven't found anything that really says, 'Hey dummy, this is what's up.'   So, I have a WPF application that references a Class library, within the Class library I create connections to and call WCF applications and it works fine.  The issue is that I have to create a service reference within my WPF in order for the program to work, even though the WPF doesn't directly interact with the WCF applications at all.  If you need any more info, or if you have any advice, please let me know.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Any information on how to fix it would be awesome as well.  Thanks again

Comment: Are you utilizing appconfig for configuration info for your wcf service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to, the only thing you need in the WPF application is the settings in the `app.config` under `<system.serviceModel>` from the class library's `app.config`.

The settings file used in a project is the executing one, so when you added the reference also to the WPF application it created an entry for `<system.serviceModel>` in your WPF app.

Comment: Assuming I'm understanding this correctly, my program won't work unless I have a service reference to the WCF applications and an app.config file in my WPF.

Comment: No, you don't need a service reference in your WPF application. The one you have in the class library is enough. What you need in your WPF application's app.config is the configuration for the service reference from the Class library.

Comment: I understand your point now, so let me rephrase my question, is there a way to make the program work without having to make a reference from the app.config or service reference, etc. to the WCF from within my WPF at all.

Comment: Yes, it is. If you for some reason don't want to have configuration in the WPF application you can set endpoint address and binding in the class library with code. An example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647110.aspx

Comment: I think this might be what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this example of creating a dynamic proxy](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/DynamicWCFproxy.aspx)

The reference you need to set is probably needed because you are using (generated) classes that implement interfaces or inherit from classes in that assembly.

A generated proxy inherits from